# Python Selenium doesn't click on element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, button, youtube, click

I want to create a code that dispute copyrights on youtube studio but when selenium have to click the button in the photo(with xpath://*[@id="text-item-6"]/ytcp-ve/tp-yt-paper-item-body/div/div/div/yt-formatted-string)
[button that can not be clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OykY5.png)
it does nothing like the element is not there. This is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from time import sleep  

def suppress_exception_in_del(uc):
    old_del = uc.Chrome.__del__

    def new_del(self) -> None:
        try:
            old_del(self)
        except:
            pass
    
    setattr(uc.Chrome, '__del__', new_del)

suppress_exception_in_del(uc)


chrome_options = Options()


driver = uc.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, driver_executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())

achains = ActionChains(driver)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 120)


driver.get('https://studio.youtube.com')



email = 'email'
password = 'password'


emailins = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="identifierId"]')))
emailins.send_keys(email)

emailbutton = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id ="identifierNext"]')))
emailbutton.click()

passwordins = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')))
passwordins.send_keys(password)

passwardbutton = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id ="passwordNext"]')))
passwardbutton.click()

contbutton = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="menu-paper-icon-item-1"]')))
contbutton.click()

filtlist = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filter-icon"]')))
filtlist.click()

copyr = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="text-item-4"]')))
copyr.click()

sleep(5)

morehover = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="row-container"]/div[4]/div')
achains.move_to_element(morehover).perform()

sleep(2)

see = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="tooltip"]/ytcp-video-restrictions-tooltip-body/div/a/ytcp-button/div')))
see.click()

opt = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="action-button"]')))
opt.click()


disp = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="text-item-6"]/ytcp-ve/tp-yt-paper-item-body/div/div/div/yt-formatted-string')))
disp.click()
```

Could you please explain me what is the problem and suggest solutions?